# Print detail list content in a new page in Jasper Report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a jasper report that has main report and detail report as a list, the data is being sent from server side Java as a java bean that has some attributes including a list of another Java bean, this list is used to fill the detail list, the problem is that, the client need that each detail record should be in a separate page

I already try to use Break at end of the list layout, but when I try to generate the report I got the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBreak.prepare(JRFillBreak.java:218)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.prepareElements(JRFillElementContainer.java:537)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.components.list.FillListContents.prepare(FillListContents.java:92)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.components.list.VerticalFillList.fillContents(VerticalFillList.java:164)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.components.list.VerticalFillList.prepare(VerticalFillList.java:111)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillComponentElement.prepare(JRFillComponentElement.java:152)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.prepareElements(JRFillElementContainer.java:537)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:411)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:386)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2024)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:748)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:255)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:115)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:582)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseReportFiller.fill(BaseReportFiller.java:414)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:121)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:667)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:983)
```

Here's the java code for generating the report:

*due to sensitive client information I couldn't provide the exact code but the same structure*

#### Report Bean:

```
public class ReportBean implements Serializable {

    // Main attributes used in the Main report Header and Footer
    private String attr1;
    private String attr2;
    private List<DetailBean> list;

    // setters and getters
}
```

#### Detail Bean:

```
public class DetailBean implements Serializable {

    // Detail attributes used in the list details to show detail records
    private String attr1;
    private String attr2;

    // setters and getters
}
```

#### Generating Report:

```
// createReport() function retrieve data from data base, fill the main report information and the detail report list
ReportBean report = createReport();
String filename = "";
byte[] result = null;
try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(filename)) {
    result = JasperReportsGenerator.createPDF(is, Collections.singletonList(report), params);
}
catch (IOException e) {}
```

And here's the report structure:

#### Main Report:

[image: Main Report]

#### List details:

[image: List details]

#### Report structure:

[image: Report structure]

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should post small but full (jrxml + Java code) example to reproduce the issue

Comment: Just a guess: it might not be possible to use page break inside of a list - you should try doing the same with a subreport or table.